# Gulp SASS, autoprefixer, minify and sourcemaps generate huge file

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat, gulp-sourcemaps, gulp-ruby-sass, gulp-rename

I'm experiencing strange behaviour using this Gulp configuration to minify my SASS files generating sourcemaps.

```
'use strict';

var PATH = {
    SRC_DIR: 'src/',
    SRC: {
        IMG: 'img/',
        INDEX: 'index.html',
        JS: {
            DIR: 'js/',
            FILE: [
                'app.js',
                '**/*.js',
                'controller/**/*.js',
                'factory/**/*.js',
                'directive/**/*.js',
                'model/**/*.js'
            ]
        },
        SASS: 'sass/',
        TEMPLATE: 'template/'
    },
    DEST_DIR: 'dist/',
    DEST: {
        CSS: {
            DIR: 'css/',
            FILE: 'full.css'
        },
        IMG: 'img/',
        JS: {
            DIR: 'js/',
            FILE: 'full.js'
        },
        LIB: 'lib/',
        TEMPLATE: 'template/',
    }
};

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return sass(PATH.SRC_DIR + PATH.SRC.SASS, {
        sourcemap: true,
        style: 'expanded'
    })
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 version', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9'],
        cascade: true
    }))
    .pipe(concat(PATH.DEST.CSS.FILE))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.DEST_DIR + PATH.DEST.CSS.DIR))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.DEST_DIR + PATH.DEST.CSS.DIR));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(PATH.SRC_DIR + PATH.SRC.SASS + '**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'styles']);
```

The first time I run this script using `gulp` it'll generate a correct `full.min.css` and it waits for changes in the SASS directory.

When you change something inside SASS files it'll trigger the watch and re-run the `styles` task, which will build a `full.min.css`.

You see the changes in the front-end but this minified file becomes bigger and bigger at every rebuild.

If I omit the sourcemaps inside `styles` task it seems to work fine.
The `full.css` file is always ok.

What am I missing here? Why the minified version keeps increasing its dimension?

Comment: Help me out there... why do you concatenate your `full.css` file with your new sass output?

Comment: Ok, this is not my intention, and it could be another error here.
I only want to get `full.css` via concatenation of SASS compiled files (CSS) and `full.min.css` which is the minified version with sourcemaps.
Which is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: So you mean to get the name of that file? Or do you want to get the contents. For the first one, you just can use the `rename` task. It would make sense that your files grow bigger that way, because MinifyCSS actually removes duplicates, but the sourcemaps still need to know where all came from.

Comment: File naming is correct, I get 2 files with contents according to their names.
The problem is the content growing on each build in the `full.min.css`.
Now I see your point, for me is ok also to get the `full.css` as concatenation and sourcemaps (useful for debugging SASS), and get the `full.min.css` minified without sourcemaps.

Comment: Sorry that I kept you waiting. Could you perhaps put your sourcemap to a pastebin.com? I'd like to look at what's getting merged. I've the feeling that you have some sort of loop here, concatenating the same file over and over, with minifycss removing it again.

Comment: Here the output, [full.css](http://pastebin.com/LnZjBjiA) and [full.min.css](http://pastebin.com/U89nC2AJ) with source map.
I've also rewritten it using `gulp-sass`, here the [PoC](http://pastebin.com/5cbD9hxy).

Comment: There's one thing missing in your current Gulpfile from the one stated in the question... that's the `concat` part which merges the file with itself -- maybe your file doesn't grow anymore. :) To me the current version looks really good